# Inputting numbers into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble getting my functions right for a program I am writing for a homework assignment. The assignment asks me to write a lottery simulation in which the user guesses 7 numbers between 1 and 40. the numbers are then compared to randomly generated numbers from a separate function. This function is meant to ask for and store the 7 numbers in an array:

```
const int size = 7;

int getLottoPicks(int userNum[size]) { //collects and stores the user input

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   cout << "Please enter number " << i+1 << ": ";
     cin >> userNum[i];

 if (userNum[i] < 1 || userNum[i] > 40) { //keeps the number between 1 and 40
   cout << "The number must between 1 and 40." << endl
        << "Please enter another number: ";
     cin >> userNum[i];
}
}

return userNum[size];
}
```

Currently this function outputs something crazy like *0096F71C* instead of the inputted numbers.

What modifications do I have to make to get this to output a 7 number array when called?
Also, what would be the best way to find and prevent duplicate values from being input by the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't output anything other than the prompt. And it returns an element one-past the end of your array. You have undefined behavior going on here.

I'd suggest you don't need to return anything, since your function already inserts into the array it was given. Now to fix it, you can do the following:

```
const int size = 7;

void getLottoPicks(int userNum[size]) { //collects and stores the user input

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << "Please enter number " << i+1 << ": ";
      cin >> userNum[i];

    if (userNum[i] < 1 || userNum[i] > 40) {
      cout << "The number must between 1 and 40." << endl
           << "Please enter another number: ";
      cin >> userNum[i];
    }

    for (int j = i; j > 0; --j) {
      if (userNum[i] == userNum[j]) {
        cout << "Already entered this number";
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. When I made these changes in my program however, it created an error when I call the function. I call it with: 
_userTicket[size] = getLottoPicks(userTicket);_
and the error I receives says _"'=': cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'"._ Am I calling this incorrectly?

Comment: @MaxOrozco, yes you are. Just declare your array `int userTicket[size];` and then call the function on a separate line.`getLottoPicks(userTicket);`